# ruby serialport gem, who is responsible to check parity errors?

Tags: ruby, serial-port, ruby-1.9

#### gems

serialport (1.0.4)
Authors: Guillaume Pierronnet, Alan Stern, Daniel E. Shipton, Tobin
Richard, Hector Parra, Ryan C. Payne
Homepage: http://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport/
Library for using RS-232 serial ports.

I am using this gem, and my device's specifications are as follows.

- 9600bps
- 7bits
- 1 stop bit
- EVEN parity

When I receive data like below, the unpacked data is still with parity bit.

```rb
sp = SerialPort.new("/dev/serial-device", 9600, 7, 1, SerialPort::EVEN)
data = sp.gets
data.chars.each do |char|
  puts char.unpack("B*")
end
```

ex. if `sp` receives `a`, the unpacked data is `11100001` instead of `01100001`, because it's EVEN parity.

---

To convert the byte back the what it should be, I do like this

```rb
data = sp.gets #gets 11100001 for 'a' (even parity)
data.bytes.to_a.each do |byte|
  puts (byte & 127).chr
end
```

now, to me, this is a way low-level.  I was expecting the serialport gem was to do this parity check, but as far as I read its document, it doesn't say anything about parity check.

Am I missing a method that is already implemented in the gem, or is my work around above is nessesary since it's my responsibity to check the parity and find error?

Comment: I know this doesn't help much but normally the parity check is handled by the serial port driver itself. Ruby should be going through the serial driver.

Comment: so I guess the driver is passing data as is (this means that I am responsible to check parity).  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I think the 0x80 bit is not the parity bit but the serial port driver setting the 8th bit to 1 out of convention.  Is it 1 all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SerialPort::ODD, SerialPort::MARK, SerialPort::SPACE
(MARK and SPACE are not supported on Posix)

Raise an argError on bad argument.

SerialPort::new and SerialPort::open without a block return an
instance of SerialPort. SerialPort::open with a block passes
a SerialPort to the block and closes it when the block exits
(like File::open).

** Instance methods **

- modem_params() -> aHash
- modem_params=(aHash) -> aHash
- get_modem_params() -> aHash
- set_modem_params(aHash) -> aHash
- set_modem_params(baudrate [, databits [, stopbits [, parity]]])

Get and set the modem parameters. Hash keys are "baud", "data_bits",
"stop_bits", and "parity" (see above).

Parameters not present in the hash or set to nil remain unchanged.
Default parameter values for the set_modem_params method are:
databits = 8, stopbits = 1, parity = (databits == 8 ?
SerialPort::NONE : SerialPort::EVEN).

- baud() -> anInteger
- baud=(anInteger) -> anInteger
- data_bits() -> 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8
- data_bits=(anInteger) -> anInteger
- stop_bits() -> 1 or 2
- stop_bits=(anInteger) -> anInteger
- parity() -> anInteger: SerialPort::NONE, SerialPort::EVEN,
  SerialPort::ODD, SerialPort::MARK, or SerialPort::SPACE
- parity=(anInteger) -> anInteger

Get and set the corresponding modem parameter.

- flow_control() -> anInteger
- flow_control=(anInteger) -> anInteger

Get and set the flow control: SerialPort::NONE, SerialPort::HARD,
SerialPort::SOFT, or (SerialPort::HARD | SerialPort::SOFT).

Note: SerialPort::HARD mode is not supported on all platforms.
SerialPort::HARD uses RTS/CTS handshaking; DSR/DTR is not
supported.

- read_timeout() -> anInteger
- read_timeout=(anInteger) -> anInteger
- write_timeout() -> anInteger
- write_timeout=(anInteger) -> anInteger

Get and set timeout values (in milliseconds) for reading and writing.
A negative read timeout will return all the available data without
waiting, a zero read timeout will not return until at least one
byte is available, and a positive read timeout returns when the
requested number of bytes is available or the interval between the
arrival of two bytes exceeds the timeout value.

Note: Read timeouts don't mix well with multi-threading.

Note: Under Posix, write timeouts are not implemented.

- break(time) -> nil

Send a break for the given time.

time -> anInteger: tenths-of-a-second for the break.
Note: Under Posix, this value is very approximate.

- signals() -> aHash

Return a hash with the state of each line status bit. Keys are
"rts", "dtr", "cts", "dsr", "dcd", and "ri".

Note: Under Windows, the rts and dtr values are not included.

- rts()
- dtr()
- cts()
- dsr()
- dcd()
- ri() -> 0 or 1
- rts=(0 or 1)
- dtr=(0 or 1) -> 0 or 1

Get and set the corresponding line status bit.

Note: Under Windows, rts() and dtr() are not implemented